# Getting "Unable to get commandbar : Tools" Error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, wspbuilder

I've just installed Visual Studio 2010 along with WSPBuilder Extensions 2.0 (Beta) for use with Sharepoint. When I install WSPBuilder Extensions I get the "Unable to get commandbar : Tools" pop-up error upon opening Visual Studio 2010. As a result, I do not get any of the WSPBuilder tools available.

Has anyone else experienced this issue? I've tried uninstalling/re-installing just about everything. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

UDPATE:

I figured out I was using an outdated version of WSPBuilder Extensions. I was able to get the latest version of WSPBuilder Extensions (v2.0) to solve this error.